# Find a sequence in a matrix as efficiently as possible

Tags: r, performance, matrix, sequence

**Few requirements.**

*Before posting your answer please!!*

`1)` Make sure that your function does not give errors with other data, simulate several similar matrices. (turn off the seed)

`2)` Make sure your function is faster than mine

`3)` Make sure that your function works exactly the same as mine, simulate it on different matrices (turn off the seed)

for example

```
 for(i in 1:500){
    m <- matrix(sample(c(F,T),30,T),ncol = 3) ; colnames(m) <- paste0("x",1:ncol(m))
    
    res <- c(my_fun(m),your_function(m))
    print(res)
    if(sum(res)==1)  break
    }
    m
```

`4)` the function should work with a matrix with any number of rows and columns

**==========================================================**
The function looks for a `true` in the first column of the logical matrix, if a true is found, go to column 2 and a new row, and so on..
If the sequence **is found return `true` if not `false`**

```
set.seed(15)
m <- matrix(sample(c(F,T),30,T),ncol = 3) ; colnames(m) <- paste0("x",1:ncol(m))
m
         x1    x2    x3
 [1,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [6,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[10,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

my slow example function

```
find_seq <- function(m){
colum <- 1
res <- rep(FALSE,ncol(m))
for(i in 1:nrow(m)){
    if(m[i,colum]==TRUE){
      res[colum] <- TRUE
      print(c(row=i,col=colum))
      colum <- colum+1}
  if(colum>ncol(m)) break
}

 all(res)
}
```

[image]

```
find_seq(m)
row col 
  3   1 
row col 
  4   2 
row col 
  9   3 
[1] TRUE
```

**how to make it as fast as possible?**

**UPD=========================**

```
 microbenchmark::microbenchmark(Jean_Claude_Arbaut_fun(m),
+                                ThomasIsCoding_fun(m),
+                                my_fun(m))
Unit: microseconds
                      expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq     max neval cld
 Jean_Claude_Arbaut_fun(m)  2.850  3.421  4.36179  3.9915  4.5615  27.938   100 a  
     ThomasIsCoding_fun(m) 14.824 15.965 17.92030 16.5350 17.1050 101.489   100  b 
                 my_fun(m) 23.946 24.517 25.59461 25.0880 25.6580  42.192   100   c
```

Comment: As fast as possible? I'd try Rcpp. An easily optimized loop in C++.

Comment: Can you halp me with that?

Comment: This reads more like an assignment than a question.  You're basically asking people to submit completed and fully tested work to you - with **requirements**.  There isn't a question here, it's a work request : please make my code faster.  StackOverflow is here to help you **understand** how to make your code more performant, not to **deliver** tested, working solutions to you.

Comment: no need to wishful thinking .. Stackoverflow is questions on the code, and not theoretical reasoning, there are other resources for this. I took a small part of my algorithm and asked how to do it faster, I did not say write all the code for me. So there is no need to invent something that does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, a single loop through the rows is enough. Here is a way to do this with Rcpp. Here I only return the true/false answer, if you need the indices, it's also doable.

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('
bool hasSequence(LogicalMatrix m) {
  int nrow = m.nrow(), ncol = m.ncol();
  
  if (nrow > 0 && ncol > 0) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
      if (m(i, j)) {
        if (++j >= ncol) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}')


a <- matrix(c(F, F, T, T, F, T, F, F, F, F,
              T, F, T, T, F, T, T, F, F, F,
              T, F, T, T, F, F, F, F, T, T), ncol = 3)

a
hasSequence(a)
```

In order to get also the indices, the following function returns a list, with at least one element (named 'found', true or false) and if found = true, another element, named 'indices':

```
cppFunction('
List findSequence(LogicalMatrix m) {
  int nrow = m.nrow(), ncol = m.ncol();

  IntegerVector indices(ncol);
  if (nrow > 0 && ncol > 0) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
      if (m(i, j)) {
        indices(j) = i + 1;
        if (++j >= ncol) {
          return List::create(Named("found") = true,
                              Named("indices") = indices);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return List::create(Named("found") = false);
}')

findSequence(a)
```

A few links to learn about Rcpp:

- [High performance functions with Rcpp](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html), Hadley Wickham
- [Rcpp for everyone](https://teuder.github.io/rcpp4everyone_en/), Masaki E. Tsuda
- [Interfacing R with C/C++](https://mfasiolo.github.io/sc2-2019/rcpp/), Matteo Fasiolo
- [Rcpp Gallery](https://gallery.rcpp.org/) - Articles and code examples for the Rcpp package

You have to know at least a bit of C language (preferably C++, but for a basic usage, you can think of Rcpp as C with some magic syntax for R data types). The first link explains the basics of Rcpp types (vectors, matrices and lists, how to allocate, use and return them). The other links are good complements.

Comment: 1) yes indexes would be better 2) your function doesn't work identical to mine check this test  http://prntscr.com/iqsrfiOVZbul

Comment: @mr.T Apart from the printing of indices, I get the same answer. It's not difficult to see that both functions do the same thing (actually it's already a good test, I initially only considered the example, not the code). If you want something fast, don't print. If you want to output indices instead of true/false, as I said it's doable, but I'd like first to clarify that this function is correct, as it seems.

Comment: Yes, it works great!! I have a small request, could you add comments to the code so that I can learn this wonderful c++.
And please make it possible to print or not print indexes

Comment: @mr.T All right. Sorry to insist, but do you really want to print? It might be more interesting to return the vector of indices?

Comment: Yes, yes you are right, I need a vector.
I guess I didn't understand you at first. Thanks for asking again

Answer (score 7):

## Update

If you are pursuing the speed, you can try the following base R solution

```
TIC_fun <- function(m) {
    p <- k <- 1
    nr <- nrow(m)
    nc <- ncol(m)
    repeat {
        if (p > nr) {
            return(FALSE)
        }
        found <- FALSE
        for (i in p:nr) {
            if (m[i, k]) {
                # print(c(row = i, col = k))
                p <- i + 1
                k <- k + 1
                found <- TRUE
                break
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            return(FALSE)
        }
        if (k > nc) {
            return(TRUE)
        }
    }
}
```

and you will see

```
Unit: microseconds
       expr    min      lq      mean  median      uq       max neval
  my_fun(m) 18.600 26.3010  41.46795 41.5510 44.3010   121.302   100
 TIC_fun(m) 10.201 14.1515 409.89394 22.6505 24.4005 38906.601   100
```

---

## Previous Answer

You can try the code below

```
lst <- with(as.data.frame(which(m, arr.ind = TRUE)), split(row, col))
# lst <- apply(m, 2, which)

setNames(
    stack(
        setNames(
            Reduce(function(x, y) y[y > x][1],
                lst,
                init = -Inf,
                accumulate = TRUE
            )[-1],
            names(lst)
        )
    ),
    c("row", "col")
)
```

which gives

```
  row col
1   3   1
2   4   2
3   9   3
```

---

A more interesting implementation might be using the ***recursions*** (just for fun, but not recommanded due to the inefficiency)

```
f <- function(k) {
    if (k == 1) {
        return(data.frame(row = which(m[, k])[1], col = k))
    }
    s <- f(k - 1)
    for (i in (tail(s, 1)$row + 1):nrow(m)) {
        if (m[i, k]) {
            return(rbind(s, data.frame(row = i, col = k)))
        }
    }
}
```

and which gives

```
> f(ncol(m))
  row col
1   3   1
2   4   2
3   9   3
```

Comment: What about just `lst <- apply(m, 2, which)`?

Comment: @Maël yes, excellent!

Comment: please see my update

Comment: I love the solution using reduce, if speed really matters on very big matrices I would prefer `y[y > x[1]][1]` over evaluating all to get the min, which is always the first value. To create the output I think `data.frame(row = "your reduce function", col = colnames(m)` would do ;)

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg Nice catch! I updated my answer as per your advice, thanks!

Comment: @mr.T Thanks for the benchmark! I updated my solution as well and it can speed up a little bit (but slower than yours). If you are after a outperformant one, I guess Rcpp might be a good option.

Comment: @mr.T See my update

Comment: The function works identically to mine, but sometimes gives an error, you can check this by simulating the work of the function with this code prntscr.com/iqsrfiOVZbul

Comment: @mr.T Okay, I see. I forgot to add one more line to my code. You can try the update again.

Answer (score 5):

If your example is representative, we assume that `nrow(m) >> ncol(m)`. In that case, it would be more efficient to move the interation from rows to columns:

```
ff = function(m)
{
  i1 = 1
  for(j in 1:ncol(m)) {
    if(i1 > nrow(m)) return(FALSE)
    i1 = match(TRUE, m[i1:nrow(m), j]) + i1
    #print(i1)
    if(is.na(i1)) return(FALSE) 
  }
  return(TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Your function sometimes gives an error :  Error in m[i1:nrow(m), j] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @mr.T : Should be fixed now. It was just a missing check for when a `TRUE` was found at the last row

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to fix this

Answer (score 4):

A bit ugly (cause of the `<<-`), but it will get the job done..

```
tempval <- 0
lapply(split(m, col(m)), function(x) {
  value <- which(x)[which(x) > tempval][1]
  tempval <<- value
  return(value)
})

# $`1`
# [1] 3
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 4
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 9
```

Comment: Your function does not work identically to mine, you can check this by running the code that I gave from the very beginning at the top

Answer (score 4):

Here a function that focuses on case handling. It's faster than all, hope it's right :)

```
f <- \(m) {
  stopifnot(dim(m)[2] == 3L)
  e <- nrow(m)
  x1 <- if (any(xx1 <- m[, 1])) {
    which.max(xx1)
  } else {
    NA_integer_
  }
  x2 <- if (is.na(x1)) {
    NA_integer_
  }
  else if (any(xx2 <- m[(x1 + 1):e, 2])) {
    which.max(xx2) + x1
  } else {
    NA_integer_
  }
  x3 <- if (is.na(x2)) {
    NA_integer_
  }
  else if (any(xx3 <- m[(x2 + 1):e, 3])) {
    which.max(xx3) + x2
  } else {
    NA_integer_
  }
  !anyNA(c(x1, x2, x3))
}

f(m)
# [1] TRUE

m2 <- m
m2[, 3] <- FALSE

f(m2)
# [1] FALSE
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(15)
m <- matrix(sample(c(FALSE, TRUE), 30, TRUE), ncol=3)
```

Comment: Hey! please edit your answer : the function should work with a matrix with any number of rows and columns

Answer (score 3):

With `accumulate`:

```r
purrr::accumulate(apply(m, 2, which), .init = -Inf, ~ min(.y[.y > min(.x)]))[-1]

# or

purrr::accumulate(apply(m, 2, which), .init = -Inf, ~ .y[.y > .x][1])[-1]

# x1 x2 x3 
#  3  4  9
```

Comment: Your function does not work identically to mine, you can check this by running the code that I gave from the very beginning at the top